# Please check if my reasoning for proof is legal or not

Tags: proof-verification

If I have proved a theorem $A$ on the basis of fact $B$,
then, is it valid to prove $B$ by using the theorem $A$?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning).

Comment: No, It is not. That amounts to saying that B is true because B is true.

Comment: Term "fact" usually refers to some "true" statement. Such statement needs no proof (it is "already" true). If you did only prove that $B \implies A$ then: 1) not necessarily $B$ is true (counterexample: $x=y \implies |x|=|y|$, but $x=y$ doesn't hold for arbitrary $(x,y)$); 2) not necessarily $A \implies B$ is true (counterexample the same).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends. If your goal is to show that the theorems are *equivalent*, then it is valid. If your goal is to show that the theorems are *true*, then it is not valid, but a case of circular reasoning.

As an example of how circular reasoning doesn't work to establish truth, consider the following:

**Theorem A:** $1=0$.

**Theorem B:** $2=0$.

I now prove A from B: Given $2=0$, I can multiply both sides of the equation with $\frac12$, and obtain $1=0$ $\square$

I also prove B from A: Given $1=0$, I can multiply both sides of the equation with $2$, and obtain $2=0$. $\square$

So if that sort of reasoning would establish truth, I would now have proven that $1=0$ and $2=0$.

However, what this reasoning *did* establish is that both claims are equivalent, so should I somehow manage to prove *any* of them, the other will also automatically be proved. And should I manage to *disprove* any of them, the other will also automatically be disproved.